# Why my memory check code didn't work well

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, operating-system

I'm trying to Implement simple OS and now have to implement memory management.

At first, we typed simple code code to check memory size as below.

What the problem i met is that the result of this function depends on increment size.
If I set increment to 1024, this function return 640Kb.
However, If I set increment to 1024*1024, this functinon return 120Mb.
(my system(bochs)'s memory set to 120MB.)
I checked the optimization option and A20 gate.

Anyone who knows why my function didn't work well?

```
unsigned int memtest_sub(unsigned int start, unsigned int end)
{
    unsigned int    i;  
    unsigned int*   ptr;
    unsigned int    orgValue;   
    const unsigned int  testValue = 0xbfbfbfbf;

    for (i = start; i <= end; i += 1024*1024) {
        ptr = (unsigned int*) i;
        orgValue = *ptr;
        *ptr = testValue;
        if (*ptr != testValue) {
            break;
        }   
        *ptr = orgValue;
    }   
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Don't probe memory. Use the BIOS (as it looks you're on x86) while in real mode to get the memory layout. See int 15h.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do probes like that.

First the memory isn't necessarily contiguous as you've already discovered. It almost never is. The hole at 640k is for legacy reasons, but even further in the memory is usually split up. You have to ask your firmware for the memory layout.

Second some memory banks might be double mapped into the physical space and you'll end up in real trouble if you start using them. This isn't very common, but it's a real pain to deal with it.

Third, and probably most important, there are devices mapped into that space. By writing to random addresses you're potentially writing to registers of important hardware. Writing back whatever you read won't do you good because some hardware registers have side effects as soon as you write them. As a matter of fact, some hardware registers have side effects when you read them. Some of that hardware isn't necessarily protected and you might do permanent damage. I've bricked ethernet hardware in the past by having pointer errors in a 1:1 mapped kernel because the EEPROM/flash was unprotected. Other places you write to might actually change the layout of the memory itself.

Since you're most likely on i386 read this: http://wiki.osdev.org/Detecting_Memory_(x86)

Also, consider using a boot loader that detects memory for you and communicates that and other important information you need to know in a well defined API. The boot loader is better debugged with respect to all weird variants of hardware.

Comment: Thank you for kind reply. It is very helpful to me. All the time, I feel that more study is needed. ^^~!

Comment: @joejo Just keep learning by doing. This is an endless field, especially since hardware manufacturers will make new weird designs and errors faster than you can learn them all. Operating systems are by far the most satisfying software to get running though.

Answer (score 1):

Following assignments are buggy:

```
    ptr = (unsigned int*) i;
    orgValue = *ptr;
    *ptr = testValue;
```

`ptr` not pointing any valid memory, you can't treat `i`'s value as address where you can perform some read-write operation - Undefined behaviour

Comment: Note that as a kernel you can read/write at any memory location, especially with interrupts disabled.

Comment: @Macmade While technically true (even though accessing some memory will just NMI you to death interrupts enabled or disabled), it's a terrible idea because of hardware registers all over the place.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Links to information about this will be pretty much any CPU documentation. http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.pdf is a good start, the most relevant volume (3) starts at page 1868, chapters 3-6, 3.2.1 describes the mode the code in the question is probably running under. Unfortunately the CPU documentation isn't enough, you also need to have the architecture documentation for what BIOS does to set up your machine. Look around at http://wiki.osdev.org/ to find something relevant.

Comment: @Art That's why I added a comment in the question about int 15... : )

Comment: I appreciate your interest. Next time i try to define address variable as pointer type.